# How to save variables from functions?

Tags: php

The function `fun()` is calculating a series of values in a variable called `$short`.

I want to be able to access the values calculated in a previous execution of the `fun()` function (saving all the results in one array).

How can I save each value of the `$short` variable in the array `$arrB` so that it is accessible after the function returns?

```php
<?php
$arrA=array('a','b','c','d','e');
$arrB=array();// ### ? ###

function fun($param)
{
 for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
 {
  $short='['.$param.$i.']';
  echo$short;
  array_push($arrB,$short);// ### ? ###
 }
}

foreach($arrA as $var)
{
 fun($var);
}

print_r($arrB);// ### ? ###
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$arrB` does not exist **inside** your function.  You could declare this variable 'global', ie: declare that it exists **outside** your function - this way your function could modify it.

```
function fun($param) {

    global $arrB;

    for(...){
        .....
    }  

}
```

Alternatively, you could pass `$arrB` into your function **by reference**, which will have a similar effect  of the function modifying the **original** variable.

```
function fun($param, &$arrB){

    .....

}
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like the reference solution is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a static variable:

```
php > function foo ($x) {
    static $arr = array();
    $arr[] = $x;
    var_dump($arr);
}
php > foo(1);
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
}
php > foo('hi mom!');
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  string(7) "hi mom!"
}
```

This allows the "staticked" variable to stay alive after its containing function returns. Without the `static` keyword, `$arr` would get initialized on every call to the function, and the array would only ever containg one thing.

If you need the variable available outside the function, then either use this `static` method, and return the new array. Or just use a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

the global keyword

http://php.net/language.variables.scope

```
global $arrB;
```